# How to retrieve Email from Facebook SDK

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

Note: please do not close as duplicate, I went through almost every existing thread here on Stackoverflow, but my problem is still not solved.

This is my **Swift 3** function with the latest Facebook SDK:

```
let req = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields":"email,name"], tokenString: token?.tokenString, version: nil, httpMethod: "GET")
_ = req?.start(completionHandler: { (connection, result, error : Error?) -> Void in

    if(error == nil) {
         print("result \(result)")
    } else {
         print("error \(error!)")
    }
})
```

Result:

```
result Optional({
    id = 102080884567XXXXX;
    name = "David Seek";
})
```

Email permission is *approved*:

[image]

Also the App is in live mode:

[image]

I have checked the [reference guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/#reference-email), but I can't find my mistake.

**My problem is, that I'm saving the facebookID as Email adress** into my backend and I'm trying to figure out why... Therefore I have tried the provided code on top, but I'm not receiving the Email.

```
let result = FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application,
                                                                   open: url,
                                                                   sourceApplication: sourceApplication,
                                                                   annotation: annotation)
if result {

    let token = FBSDKAccessToken.current()
    let fieldsMapping = [
        "id" : "facebookId",
        "name" : "name",
        "birthday": "birthday",
        "first_name": "fb_first_name",
        "last_name" : "fb_last_name",
        "gender": "gender",
        "email": "email"
    ]

    backendless?.userService.login(withFacebookSDK: token, fieldsMapping: fieldsMapping, response: { (user: BackendlessUser?) in

    }, error: { (fault: Fault?) -> Void in
        print("Server reported an error: \(fault)")
    })
}
```

I'm receiving every information, but the Email...

What am I missing? Help is very appreciated.

Comment: _"Email permission is granted:"_ - that is not what that screenshot shows. It shows that it is _approved_, meaning your app _can_ ask users for it. But it still _has to ask_. Mkae sure that has happend successfully - either by debugging the access token, or via call to /me/permissions

Comment: okay i see. could you tell me more about the ` via call to /me/permissions` i will debug the access token in the meantime

Comment: okay `token?.hasGranted("email")` prints `false`

Comment: how do i grant it then? :/

Comment: dang facebook docs to implementing Facebook login is broken `Sorry, the link you followed may be broken, or the page may have been removed.`

Comment: will google it. thank you very much for that

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/swift/login

Comment: that? but I'm doing that. i'm using loginButton and am logging in a user

Comment: okay getting to it. i guess i need to provide the wanted permissions for the button.

Comment: @CBroe thanks. you helped me alot. i forgot to enter `.email` to the asked permissions of the login button. thank you very much 

please fell free to answer it. and i will accept.

refer to this guide https://developers.facebook.com/docs/swift/login

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Email permission is granted:

That is not what that screenshot shows. It shows that it is *approved*, meaning your app *can* ask users for it. But it still *has to ask*.

Make sure that has happend successfully - either by debugging the access token, or via an API call to `/me/permissions`

You need to ask the user for permission during login.